# autocomplete for php tags

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I just downloaded aptana 3 Standalone Version.

until now i'v used eclipse galileo pdt for my php development.
In eclipse I had autocomplete for php tags (i.e when I type
   `<?`
eclipse autocompletes it to `<?php ?>`)

How can I enable this for aptana 3?

when I google for this I always get that it isn't possible in aptana.. Is this right?